# Parent Child Datagrids have different ItemsSource in MVVM

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a DataGrid and in that DataGrid's DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate I have put another DataGrid.Now my first Datagrid is having ItemsSource="{Binding MatchObsCollection}" and My inner Datagrid which is in my DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate has separate ItemSource. But inner Datagrid is notpopulating. I am using MVVM and I am binding both the Datagrid s by ObservableCollections on Viewmodel. Can anyone help me please(My question is almost same as [Displaying hierarchal parent child data in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773162/displaying-hierarchal-parent-child-data-in-wpf-datagrid)  but I have not found any good answer in that post also) .My xaml code is attached below.Thanking you,

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" x:Name="dataGridParent" ItemsSource="{Binding MatchObsCollection}"
                      Style="{StaticResource EfesDataGridStyle}" FrozenColumnCount="14" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
                      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" Cursor="Hand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" 
                      util:ParentMatchDataGridRowClickHandler.MethodName="ParentMatchDatagrdRowClick"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMatch}"
                      >
<DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod" Binding="{Binding MatchNo}"  Width="50*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tarih" Binding="{Binding MatchDate}" Width="70*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ev Sahibi" Binding="{Binding MatchHome}" Width="100*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Konuk" Binding="{Binding MatchVisitor}" Width="50*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Binding="{Binding MatchResultHomeOdds}" Width="30*" ></DataGridTextColumn>                 

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding MatchResultDrawOdds}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Binding="{Binding MatchResultVisitorOdds}" Width="30*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="T1" Binding="{Binding MatchresultSingleHomeOdds}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="TX" Binding="{Binding MatchresultSingleDrawOdds}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="T2" Binding="{Binding MatchresultSingleVisitorOdds}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="+"  CellStyle ="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"  Binding="{Binding TotalBets}" Width="30*"/>


                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min" Binding="{Binding MatchMin}" Width="30*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lig" Binding="{Binding TeamName}" Width="70*" />

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Durum" Width="Auto" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ToggleButton  x:Name="toggleBtn" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource SlidingToggleButton}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" IsChecked="{Binding ToggleBtn}" Background="#FF2F63FF" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                    
                </DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate x:Uid="test123">
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="testTemplete">
                        <DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SubBetMatchDataListforChildGrid}" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource EfesDataGridStyle}" Margin="50,2,2,2" MinHeight="40"  
                                  GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#DADADA" 
                                  Visibility="Collapsed" >

<DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod" Binding="{Binding Code}" Width="3*" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alt Secenakler" Binding="{Binding SubOptions}" Width="7*" />                                
                            </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>                      
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using MVVM and I am binding both the Datagrid s by
>   ObservableCollections on Viewmodel.

You should have only one `ObservableCollection` (`MatchObsCollection`) in your ViewModel.
If you have `MatchObsCollection` and `SubBetMatchDataListforChildGrid` in ViewModel this code doesn't work.

The `DataContext` of the `RowDetails` is the row item.

So if you want to binding to the `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel you should use following code in `RowDetailsTemplate`:

```
...
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate x:Uid="test123">
        <DataTemplate x:Name="testTemplete">
            <DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.SubBetMatchDataListforChildGrid, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
...
```

If you want to binding to selected object inner `ObservableCollection` your classes should looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public int MatchNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    // more properties
    public ObservableCollection<Boo> SubBetMatchDataListforChildGrid { get; set; }
}

class Boo
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string SubOptions { get; set; }
}
```

And in the ViewModel you should have `ObservableCollection` of Foo:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> MatchObsCollection { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: many many thanks for your valuable code and elaborate explanation.I have a small request I am new to MVVM.I do post many question here if possible please answer whenever possible.

Comment: I have made it as answer.